# Javascript random number loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that should return to me a generated number of the length I have input in the input field. Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/s91fb8jx/31/

As I click the button nothing is returned, why?

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var $group = "09",
        $group_l = $group.length,
        $size = $('#size').val();

    function num_gen(num){
        var output = "";

        if(size > 0){
            while(output.length < num) {
                output += $group[Math.floor(Math.random() * $group_l)];
            }
            return output;
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        console.log(num_gen($size));
    }); 
});
```

Comment: what did you mean with one( ?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I have updated the code on the question. It is to generate a number

Comment: for a start you are setting `$size` on page load when the box is empty. Also variables `$size` and `size` aren't the same thing

Comment: `if(size > 0){` should be  `if(num > 0){`

http://jsfiddle.net/vx3qL6kc/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $group = "09",
      $group_l = $group.length;

function num_gen(num){
    var output = "";

    if(num > 0){
        while(output.length < num) {
            output += $group[Math.floor(Math.random() * $group_l)];
        }
        return output;
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}

$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    console.log(num_gen($('#size').val()));
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks! How do I prevent it to output a number that is 0 if the size is 1

Comment: What do you mean? snippet of what you're looking for it to do?

Comment: For example: If you input '1' in the input field here - http://jsfiddle.net/s91fb8jx/42/ - The output number should never be '0'. How do I do that? can you please update the answer with this?

Comment: Maybe try this --> http://jsfiddle.net/s91fb8jx/43/. put two examples, depending on what you wanted. one's based on length of input. other is based on the input iteslf

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors. First, you are getting the value of your text field before it has a value. You should get this value when the button is clicked. Second, `if(size > 0){` should be `if(num > 0){`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $group = "09",
        $group_l = $group.length;

    function num_gen(num){
        var output = "";

        if(num > 0){
            while(output.length < num) {
                output += $group[Math.floor(Math.random() * $group_l)];
            }
            return output;
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        console.log(num_gen($('#size').val())); // get the value here
    }); 
});
```